# Fibres with Nilpotents

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the *Red Book of Varieties and Scheme* and in the introduction to Chapter II, Mumford says the following

> Schemes with nilpotents are not only useful for many applications, but they come up inevitably when you examine the fibres of morphisms between quite nice varieties.

Can anyone provide and explicit example or family of examples. Better yet, when does a morphism of varieties have non-reduced fibres?

If you feel like typing, what are some of these applications of nilpotents?

Comment: Here is an easy example. Consider the map $\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1, z\mapsto z^2$. Then the fiber over $x$ is defined by the equation $z^2-x$. If $x$ is not zero, this fiber as two geometric points. However, if $x=0$, the fiber is given by the equation $z^2=0$ which gives a non reduced fiber.

Comment: Do non-reduced fibers necessarily happen at ramification points like this?

Comment: @rdrr a morphism $f : X \to Y$ is, by definition, at $x \in X$ with $y = f(x)$ unramified if $\mathfrak{m}_{y} \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \mathfrak{m}_x$ (plus some separability and finiteness conditions depending on you reference). Therefore, if $f$ is unramified at $x$ then, $\mathcal{O}_{X_y, x} = \mathcal{O}_{X,x} / \mathfrak{m}_y \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \mathcal{O}_{X,x} / \mathfrak{m}_x$ is a field so the fibers are zero dimensional and regular (in particular reduced).